# Google Maps Markers not appearing in correct location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to build a Google map of points of interest in our locality. To obtain the Lat and Long position I right click on a standard Google map select "What's Here?" (the blue X) and uses the coordinates given. However, when I open the map I created the marker is elsewhere (the pink square). This is the code I am using;

```
<script>
function initMap() {
    var map;
    var iconBase = 'icons/';
                    
    // Display a map on the web page
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
          zoom: 16,
          center: {lat: 51.4571407, lng: -0.1940732 },
          styles: [

          {
            featureType: 'poi.business',
            stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
          },

          ]
          
        });
   
    // Multiple markers location, latitude, and longitude
    var markers = [
        ['Wandsworth Town Library', 51.4562217,-0.1932119,'library.png'],,
    ];
                        
    // Info window content
    var infoWindowContent = [
        ['<div class="info_content">' +
        '<h3>Wandsworth Town Library</h3>' +
        '<p>Free blue badge holder parking during the day and first come first service parking after 4:30pm</p>' + '</div>'],
    ];
        
    // Add multiple markers to map
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
    
    // Place each marker on the map  
    for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0],
        });
        
        // Add info window to marker    
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i][0]);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

    }
    
}
// Load initialize function
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
</script>
```

How can I get the marker in the correct location, which is the blue X?

[image: The square shows where the marker ends up, the cross is the Whats Here I referened and the library is what I want to get close to.]

Comment: Look at position of 51.4562217,-0.1932119 (green cross) in the geocoder tool: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D51.456222%252C-0.193212. Marker appears exactly where you ask. Maybe you should provide correct position in your code. I think it is 51.456176,-0.192454.

Comment: @xomena Well no I clicked on the blue cross in the diagram in my OP so why is marker in geocoder appearing in different position. It seems to be that unless you zoom all the way the right-click and select what's here the co-ordinates given will not be the same as where you clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to zoom in all the way then right-click "What's here?" and use those coordinates.